# Heroku stuck at Node v0.10.30 (but package.json asks for current version)

Tags: node.js, heroku

Specify correct Node version..

```
"engines": {
    "node": "6.5.0",
    "npm": "3.10.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js buildProd",
    "start": "node server.js -p $PORT"
  }
```

When deploying, the following log is shown..

```
-----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  6.5.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   3.10.3
```

So Heroku appears to be picking up on the `engine` field of `package.json`
and installing the correct version.

But when checking Node version on Heroku...

`heroku run bash`
`node -v`
`v0.10.30`

I get the wrong version

Comment: Did you really type "Node -v" with a capital N? It should be "node -v" (not capitalised).

Comment: Nope i didn't... never the less, it works the same fyi

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Ruby Buildpack along with Node.js? Ruby requires node for certain parts of a build pipeline, and it installs 0.10.30 by default if node doesn't exist. To fix that, just put the Node.js Buildpack ahead of the Ruby buildpack, so node exists when the Ruby Buildpack runs.

Comment: Yes, I am. Ok that makes sense, I'll give it a try.